# Should my script use cp or mv to be more robust?

Tags: linux, bash, error-handling, fault, robustness

I have a bash script (Scientific Linux).
The script has to operate on a file. Let's say "file.dat" (around 1 GB of size)
After some time the scripts is restarted and executes the following:

```
if [ -f file.dat ];  then
    cp file.dat file.previous.dat
fi
```

to have a backup of the file.
Then a process starts and overwrites "file.dat"

In order to be on the safest side (electricity shut down or anything unexpected). What would be the best option: cp or mv ?
Thanks.

Comment: By "overwrites `file.dat`", do you mean the file is truncated to zero, then filled up again?

Comment: yes larsman..... (points added to comply with mimimun characters lenght)

Answer (score 5):

I would use a combination:

```
mv file.dat file.dat.previous
cp file.dat.previous file.dat
```

That way `file.dat.previous` will always be complete as `mv` is atomic.

Answer (score 4):

#### The Right Answer to the Wrong Question

If you want a quick, atomic move, then *mv* is the thing to do since `man 2 rename` says:

> If newpath already exists it will be atomically replaced (subject to a few conditions; see ERRORS below), so that there is no point at which another process attempting to access newpath will find it missing.

Perhaps more importantly, *mv* is largely a directory entry operation, so it's very quick compared to a file copy in any normal circumstance.

#### The Right Answer to the Right Question

If you're worried about power outages or unexpected system shutdowns, then:

1. Attach an uninterruptible power supply. Really. Solve for the threat model.
2. Make sure you're using a battery-backed RAID controller.
3. Make critical writes synchronous.
4. Use a journaling filesystem that journals data, and not just metadata.

The *mv* command should be faster, but robustness in the face of catastrophic failures is a hardware or filesystem issue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not too helpful here, but `rsync` is the tool for this kind of job. If the transfer gets interrupted it can restart from where it needs to go.